# Json4s custom serializer with unordered fields

Tags: scala, json4s

In the example given on the json4s readme https://github.com/json4s/json4s#serializing-non-supported-types the match only works if the fields are order {"start":0,"end":0}. If the start and end fields are swapped then the match doesn't work. Is there anyway to write the below case match such that the JSON field ordering doesn't matter?

```
case JObject(JField("start", JInt(s)) :: JField("end", JInt(e)) :: Nil)
```

Answer (score 5):

I haven't used this library, so I am not sure if this is the right approach: (I came up with this after spending a couple of minutes looking at the docs)

```
class IntervalSerializer extends CustomSerializer[Interval](format => (
  {
    case x: JObject =>
      x.obj.sortBy { case (k,_) => k } match {
        case JField("end", JInt(e)) :: JField("start", JInt(s)) :: Nil =>
          new Interval(start = s.longValue(), end = e.longValue())
      }
  },
  {
    case x: Interval =>
      JObject(JField("start", JInt(BigInt(x.startTime))) ::
        JField("end",   JInt(BigInt(x.endTime))) :: Nil)
  }
))
```

The idea is to sort the fields alphabetically, and then create the Interval class.

Answer (score 3):

I had a different but [related issue](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33413144/deserialize-nested-polymorphic-json-field-in-scalatra) that made me discover the the "extract" function in json4s. It solves the ordering issue.

```
case x: JObject =>
  Interval((x \ "start").extract[Int],(x \ "end").extract[Int])
```

If you need a more involved example, you can check this [github ticket](https://github.com/json4s/json4s/issues/308).